# Loop through all fields and change data type

Tags: ms-access, vba

Not sure what I'm missing. I'm trying to loop through all fields in a table and if any data type is <> text, then change it to text. We have some fields coming in as a number but need to convert to text before exporting as a .txt. I cannot add quotations to the field - each field must only contain numbers and letters.

I have tried the following and used the db.execute alter line for each field, but I am receiving a run time 3047 Record Too large syntax error after about the 6th field. I'm assuming it would be best to somehow loop to check each field and only change to text if it isn't already?

```
Dim table As DAO.TableDef
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

db.Execute "ALTER TABLE ImportFromExcel " _
        & "ALTER COLUMN RPT_SPLIT_ID CHAR;"
```

Comment: Is the only reason you're converting the non-text fields to text because you need to export to a .txt file? If so then I think that this is completely unnecessary. When you export the number 25 to a text file, there is no way you can tell by looking at the resulting text file what the data type of the original data was.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to cast the field as a string in your SELECT statement.  Use the CStr() function to cast whatever non-text field you have to text.  When possible, always try to collect your data with a healthy SQL query rather than looping through datasets.  It may not be a noticeable difference in smaller tables, but it makes a huge difference with large record sets.  Try this:

```
SELECT CStr(field1), CStr(field2), CStr(field3)
FROM ImportFromExcel
```

Comment: _whatever_ is a little too broad, as `CStr` will fail for _Null_ values. However, ` Ltrim(Str([field]))` will not.